# Bluemix: App diagnostic info

Tags: ibm-cloud, monitoring

I have app that uses several Bluemix services including database service.
Is it possible to have access to all available operational info via single dashboard or I need inspect all components' logs separately?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Service log files are not available. You might consider looking at the [Monitoring and Analytics service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/monitoring-and-analytics/) to see if will meet your needs. There is both a free and a diagnostics plan available.